# jQuery ul li hover effect

Tags: jquery, css, hover, html-lists

I have [this code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonur/BuJav/) and I am trying to show the nested `.submenu` lists on `ul#menu li` hover events. If you can see the `ul.submenu`'s are inside the `li`'s but for some reason when you drag your mouse from the actual `ul#menu li a` to its nested `ul.submenu` it disappears, as if you are moving out of it. I do not understand why that happens.

I have tried changing a bit the DOM as well as using `setTimeout` but with no luck.

Any ideas of how to get this done? And more importantly... why my problem occurs? I mean, since the `ul.submenu` is **inside** the `li` shouldn't it be considered the same hover area?

Comment: [Seems to work just fine in Chrome 25](http://i.imgur.com/qrCJf9E.png).

Comment: I've noticed there's a gap between the child and the parent menu. When you move your mouse quickly, it doesn't hide the child menu. This tells me that when your mouse hits that gap, that runs the code to hide the menu because you're no longer hovering over the parent menu.

Comment: @Chris Cooney: Yes that is true and I've noticed the same. Any ideas of how to overcome this?

Comment: I know it's not an ideal solution, but perhaps simply making your menu wider. You don't need to change the appearance of it, but if you alter the actual width of the UL element, while keeping the appearance the same it might keep the mouse from falling outside the list? Alternatively, removing the padding between the lists. Also noticed the hover effect is ran over the list item. When the mouse exits the list item, it's also going to hide the menu. Removing the gaps on the edges of the list item so it fills the width of the menu would probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common problem. The space between the parent menu item and `.submenu` is the culprit.

An easy fix for this is wrapping `.submenu` in a `div` that's wide enough to act as bridge between the menu item and submenu.

**See here -** http://jsfiddle.net/BuJav/15/

CSS changes-

```
.submenu-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 36px;
    top: -4px;
    left: 160px;
}
.submenu {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 160px;
    min-height: 36px;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    background: url('../images/gradient_menuarea.png') repeat-x;
}
```

**JS Changes -**

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu > li, .submenu > li').hover(
        function(){
            var submenu = $(this).find('ul.submenu');
            if (submenu.hasClass('submenu')){
                submenu.removeClass('hide');
            }
        },
        function(){
            var submenu = $(this).find('ul.submenu');
            if (submenu.hasClass('submenu')){
                submenu.addClass('hide');
            }
    });
});
```

Just so the submenu ul is targeted correctly.

---

Please note you can eliminate the JS by using this css

```
.submenu {display:none;}
#menu-area ul li:hover .submenu {display:block}
```

You won't need `.hide` class on submenu ul either

http://jsfiddle.net/BuJav/16/

Comment: Very easy and fine solution and also very well explained! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UFevL/6/

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=932K59EciV">Menu #1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=M-z-3crmAP">Menu #2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=jpHiTwH1bT">Menu #3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=Jwr0SIWoWX">Menu #4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=QY8SgMl5JH">Menu #4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=8GaCmPByu3">Menu #5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=ueHp2vYKUa">Submenu #1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=HQvyKxum8q">Submenu #2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=81cDaTOCsL">Submenu #3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=BQMppfQ0Dl">Menu #6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="?l=EL&amp;m=D3wTd4F5Mn">Menu #7</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#menu ul {
    width: 160px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #94AA13;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li + li {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    background-color: #283720;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#menu li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin: -4px 0 0 10px;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#menu li:hover > ul:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS... NONE!

The trick is in the :before element: http://caniuse.com/#search=before

If you can't use it, try adding a dummy div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is considered acceptable in your current project, but you can do a quick-fix:

```
menu-area ul li a{
   width: 100%;
   color: #F2F2F2;
   display: block;
   padding-right:10%;
}
```

You can change the value to whatever % you want that fixes your needs.  Just do it enough to make sure the  meets up with the sub-menu area.  I didn't bother checking the exact value.  Let me know if it works!