# Drop down menu not working in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My drop down menu works fine in Chrome but in IE 10 it breaks when I hover down the drop down.

**HTML**: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/index.html

```
<div id="navmenudiv">
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <div class='submenu-wrapper'>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="introduction.html">Introduction</a></li>
                <li><a href="whoweare.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
            </ul> 
            </div>               
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
            <ul class="sub1">
                <li><a href="sundaymorning.html">Sunday Morning</a></li>
                <li><a href="sundayevening.html">Sunday Evening</a></li>
                <li><a href="wednesday.html">Wednesday Evening</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News and Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS** : http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/css/styles.css

```css
#navmenudiv {
    z-index:60;
    margin: -30px 0;
    height:47px;
    background-color:#5340BF;
    top:40;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
/* rules for nav menu */
ul#navmenu, ul.sub1 {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul#navmenu > li {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
ul#navmenu li {
    width:125px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    ;
    margin-right:4px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:transparent
}
ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display:block;
    width:125px;
height 25px;
    line-height:25px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color:#CFC;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color:#FF0;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display:block;
}
/* end rules for nav menu */
```

Thanks

Comment: Skip the newline after every line you do in your html. Not a solution but it will make your code more readable.

Comment: Side comment:  I laughed when I clicked on one of the links on that site and it took me to the "Ever feel like you're in the wrong place?" error page.  Too perfect.

Comment: What do you mean with breaks and works fine? I see the same behavior in both. Remember to release your cache Ctrl F5 usually works if you performed any change to the js/css.

Comment: @porfiriopartida: I noticed in IE10 that when I try to go to one of the sub options under About Us then the menu disappears.  The spacing between menu options is too much and IE is losing the hover.

Comment: I am using IE 10. When I hover between children "Introduction" and "Who We Are" the drop down will disappear unless I do it really fast. I don't see where I have any spacing set.

Comment: Did you just post links to your local filesystem? lol

Comment: Looking at your comment `the drop down will disappear unless I do it really fast`, I think this answer might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068852/jquery-ul-li-hover-effect/15070624#15070624

Comment: I added the div wrapper to my sub1 but it still breaks in IE10. Someone please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the margin on your drop down menu items. If you remove the margin the problem does not occur.

Change this:

```css
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

To this:

```css
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Or remove those 3 lines all together.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

as your Doctype

Comment: hmmm. that makes it better but it still breaks when I hover between childs

Comment: I wouldn't use an XHTML doctype.  Either use the HTML 5 one `<!DOCTYPE html>` or use 4.01 strict.